# Cannot change hyperlink style with Word interop without changing the style of the next paragraph

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a document with a format similar to

```
Section Heading 1
    Paragraph 1
    ...
    Paragraph N
    Sub Heading 1
    Paragraph 1
    ...
    Paragraph N
```

What I am trying to do is add a hyperlink from a heading to a reference document. I can add the hyperlink and apply a style to the link but the style gets applied to the section's Paragraph 1 as well as the hyperlink.

Note: WordApp is a singleton wrapper around Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application. The HyperlinkDestionation class just holds the bookmark name and the path for the file that contains the bookmark.

```
private void LinkHeadings(string file)
{
     Document doc = WordApp.Open(file);

     for (int i = 1; i <= proposal.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
     {
        HyperlinkDestination dest = null;

        Paragraph paragraph = proposal.Paragraphs[i];
        paragraph.Range.Select();
        Style style = (Style)paragraph.get_Style();
        string styleString = ((Style)paragraph.get_Style()).NameLocal;
        string headingText = paragraph.Range.Text.Split(' ')[0];
        if (styleString.Contains("Heading"))
        {
           dest = _hyperlinkDestinations.Find(x => x.HyperlinkText == headingText);
        }

        if (dest != null)
        {
           Hyperlink link = WordApp.ActiveWindow.Document.Hyperlinks.Add(WordApp.Selection.Range, Address: dest.FilePath, SubAddress: dest.bookmarkName, TextToDisplay: WordApp.Selection.Text);
           link.Range.set_Style(style);
        }
     }

     WordApp.Close(true);
  }
```

My guess is that it has something to do with with the hyperlink anchor. I've also tried deleting the heading first then inserting the hyperlink but it also has the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that you are including the paragraph mark in the Hyperlink field that Word inserts. That pargraph mark will then be hidden when the hyperlink field result is displayed, i.e. the Section Heading 1 para. will actually become part of Paragraph 1. When you apply the style to the selection, the entire paragraph will be affected.

I'm not going to attempt to provide C# here, but here are some suggestions
 a. as a rule it is better to work with Range objects in Word than the Selection where possible, and you should be able to do so here.
 b. If you apply the Hyperlink to the paragraph without the paragraph marker, the paragraph style will be unchanged, so you should not need to re-apply it
 c. So instead of the code starting with "paragraph.Range.Select();" you should be able to use something like this (I leave you to get the C# syntax right - perhaps you can edit this message)

```
Range r = Paragraph.Range();
string headingText = r.Text.Split(' ')[0];
if (styleString.Contains("Heading"))
// you shoul probably also tst for an empty paragraph here before inserting anything (I leave it to you)
{
    dest = _hyperlinkDestinations.Find(x => x.HyperlinkText == headingText);
}

if (dest != null)
{
    // Move the end of the range one character towards the beginning
    r.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.WdCharacter,-1)
    Hyperlink link = WordApp.ActiveWindow.Document.Hyperlinks.Add(r, Address: dest.FilePath, SubAddress: dest.bookmarkName, TextToDisplay: r.Text);
}
```

If your code needs to run internationally and you *only* need to check paragraphs with the built-in style types Heading 1..Heading 9, then it would also be better to compare the Style.Type to see if it is one of those 9 style types. If you have other style types called "Heading something" that need to be included, then you probably need to check both the Style.Type and the name.

Comment: Awesome. Working with the range did the trick. I figured it was something simple like that but I just couldn't figure the range part out.